# How to avoid calling cascade of internal method structures, while doing Junit test case and mock for a particular method

Tags: java, unit-testing, junit, mockito, junit4

I'm creating a test case using Junit for a public method. This method is calling a private method in the same class and that private method is eventually calling sequence of other methods in separate classes, as per business logic.
All methods are returning a **ConcurrentHashMap** and I just want to test `assertNotNull` on the returned value.

How can I avoid the cascade of method callings?

If I go for mocking all the methods of the flow, then my test-case is becoming huge.
How can i avoid those callings and just perform a **Black-box testing** for my method only, i.e, *passing parameters* and *expected return*.

My method is:

```
public ConcurrentHashMap<String, Object> checkValidation(Validation validationData,
            ConcurrentHashMap<String, Object> srcHMData, Statement statement) {
        Column[] columnArray = validationData.getColumnArray();
        ConcurrentHashMap<String, Object> processedData = new ConcurrentHashMap<String, Object>();
        ConcurrentHashMap<String, Object> validationData = null;

        if (columnArray != null && columnArray.length > 0) {
            for (int i = 0; i < columnArray.length; i++) {
                validationData = new ConcurrentHashMap<String, Object>();
                Column colVal = columnArray[i];
                String validationName = colVal.getName();
                validationData = processValidation(validationName, srcHMData, statement);

                processedData.putAll(validationData);
            }
        }
    return processedData;

}
```

The private method that it's calling from this class is:

```
private ConcurrentHashMap<String, Object> processValidation(String validationName,
            ConcurrentHashMap<String, Object> srcHMData, Statement statement) {

        ConcurrentHashMap<String, Object> validationData = new ConcurrentHashMap<String, Object>();
        try {
            TransformationProcess transferObj = new TransformationProcess();
            validationData = transferObj.checkTransformation(srcHMData, statement);
        } catch (Exception e1) {
            e1.printStackTrace();
        }

    return validationData;

}
```

My test method something I tried like:

```
TransformationProcess transMock = mock(TransformationProcess.class);
when(transMock.checkTransformationRule(Mockito.any(), eq(dummyDataMap), eq(mockStatement))).thenReturn(validationDataMap);
```

I want to avoid internal methods calling, from this line in private method-

```
validationData = transferObj.checkTransformation(srcHMData, statement);
```

and just want to return a **mock ConcurrentHashMap** from this line,s o that I can test `assertNotNull` or some other.
But while this line encountered, it's calling the entire business flow and getting NullPointer exception eventually.

Comment: Since you have received an answer that solved your problem, it would be fair to upvote and accept it.  On stackoverflow this is more appreciated than 'thank you' comments.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use mockito for mocking the call of `new`. You have two options here: first is to go for `powermock` which can do much more that mockito but is recommended only for legacy code, the second one is to refactor your code so you can inject the dependency to `TransformationProcess` into your `Validator`.

You can directly inject the `TransformationProcess` to your method:

```
public ConcurrentHashMap<String, Object> checkValidation(Validation validationData,
            ConcurrentHashMap<String, Object> srcHMData, Statement statement, TransformationProcess transformationProcess)
```

This way doesn't look elegant, since you have to pass this dependency down to each private method that will need it.

Or the dependency can be injected via constructor:

```
Validator(TransformationProcess transformationProcess)
```

And now instead of creating the new instance each time, you can reuse the same instance that you already have in your object. In case you need a new instance of `TransformationProcess` each time, you can inject in the constructor the wrapper of `TransformationProcess` that will provide with the new instance:

```
Validator(TransformationProcessProvider transformationProcessProvider)
...
TransformationProcess transformationProcess = transformationProcessProvider.getTransformationProcess();
```

And now you can create a mock of `TransformationProcessProvider` and pass it to your object under test:

```
TransformationProcessProvider providerMock = mock(TransformationProcessProvider.class);
TransformationProcess transMock = mock(TransformationProcess.class);

when(providerMock.getTransformationProcess()).thenReturn(transMock);
when(transMock.checkTransformationRule(Mockito.any(), eq(dummyDataMap), eq(mockStatement))).thenReturn(validationDataMap);

Validator validatorUnderTest = new Validator(providerMock);
```

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. 
I will try as per your suggestion,, and let you know.

Comment: Thanks a lot,, it's working! I tried with constructor injection, and it's perfectly working. Thank you @Sergii Bishyr

Comment: @Prosenjit Glad that it works! You can always accept the question and vote up if it helped you! :)